# VueJS build multiple apps with different resources for the same project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS 2.6 and Vuetify 2.1. I'm building the same app with different resources (for different brands). For the color I'm using [Vuetify Theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme) pretty cool to change the application colors.

Each time I'm building an application I need to change manually the color, the resources (images, logos, files etc...) and the .env content. Then I run `npm run serve` for dev or `npm run build` for prod.

I'm looking for something (I imagine vue cli command) to save the brands build config, select the brand build and the build will automatically take the good resources.

So... it is possible to build multiple apps with different resources for the same project ? For example `npm build google` will build an app with Google brand with certain images, .env, files etc... and `npm build apple` will build an app with Apple brand with certain images, .env, files etc...

Comment: I guess you don't need a solution anymore, but i decided to share my answer because it could help someone who would have this same problem in the next 10 years lol

Comment: Good idea dude !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use environment variables to instruct NPM about what settings it should use to compile your application at the build time.

Also, you could use `.env` files to achieve this goal and then instruct your application to read the content of these dotEnv files based on specific environment variable.

ex:
You can define those settings inside a `.env` file

```
// .env.google file
VUE_APP_BRAND_IMAGE=src/images/google.png

// .env.apple file
VUE_APP_BRAND_IMAGE=src/images/apple.png
```

Then in your Vue App you can access this var like this.

```
<template>
  <div class="brand-image">
    <img :src="brand_image" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
const BRAND_IMAGE = process.env.VUE_APP_BRAND_IMAGE

export default {
 
  data(){
    return {
      brand_image: BRAND_IMAGE
    }
  }
}
</script>
```